# lonely runner conjecture for 3 runners

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am looking at the lonely runner conjecture and it seems that people often prove that the stationary runner is lonely for 3 runners. Why is it not considered when the other runners are lonely?

Answer (score 0):

This is just for convenience.  Any runner can be made stationary by subtracting his speed from all the speeds (possibly making some negative).